# Opening text file into dictionary - Python

Tags: python, file, dictionary, load, tuples

The text file reads

```
1
2
3
4, Eric Wont, 1/1/10, 1,2,10
5
6, John Smith, 2/2/10, 2/2/11
```

I want to store this in a dictionary with number as key and the name and both dates for value as a tuple eg

```
{4: (Eric Wont, 1/1/10, 1,2,10)}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post problems here, be sure to include a short snippet of your code showing us what you have tried so far. Helps us pinpoint your problem more accurately.

Answer (score 1):

It would look like this:

```
val_dict = {}
for line in open('a.txt'):
    vals = line.strip().split(', ', 3)                                                                                                                                
    val_dict[vals[0]] = tuple(vals[1:])
```

But that doesn't look like a big problem, more like a homework :)